# Regex find first and last element within parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex that would give me first and last elements within parentheses.

F.e. from:

`String(0xHEX1,0xHEX2,0xHEX3)`

I want to get first and last element: `0xHEX1` and `0xHEX3` (not always I operate on 3)

Previously I was using (I had always 2 elements within parentheses):

`String\S([A-Fa-f0-9]+x[A-Fa-f0-9]+),([A-Fa-f0-9]+x[A-Fa-f0-9]+)`

Comment: Please show us what have you written so far

Comment: Hint: you do not need any regex here.

Comment: What about: [`String\((?<first>0xHEX\d+).*?(?<last>0xHEX\d+)\)`](http://goo.gl/Qqz9gE) Maybe you'll change `HEX\d+` to `[0-9A-Fa-f]+`. Please keep in mind that you'll get a match of `first == last` if you've only one item.

Comment: Thanks Vera rind!, this is IT! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution is:

```
String\((?<first>0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+).*?(?<last>0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+)\)
```

Credit goes to Vera rind, who answered my question in a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Not mine but I don't think it's because of your regex. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is unnecessary, try to use the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

For example:

```
    string x = "(0xHEX1,0xHEX2,0xHEX3)";
    string y = x.Substring(1, x.Length - 2);
    string[] elements = y.Split(',');
```

After that using the `elements` variable, you will have easy access to the first and last elements.

```
string first = elements[0] //First
string last = elements[elements.Length - 1]; //Last
```

Comment: Wasn't my downvote but the question seems to suggest the parentheses are part of the string/text

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using regex, this should work for you.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"String\((?<first>0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)(,0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)*,(?<last>0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)\)");
var str = "String(0xaaaa,0xbbbb,0xcccc,0xdddd)";

var match = regex.Match(str);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["last"].Value);

Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Outputs 0xaaaa and 0xdddd

Comment: You can replace `(,0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)*` by `.*?` (see my comment for that sample).

Comment: you shouldn't when using regex rather be specific.  If you are expecting hex then you should check for hex.